# Android on Fedora: PATH not pick up?

Tags: android, path, android-ndk, installation, fedora

I am working to setup Android NDK on Fedora 16 AMD. So far... I have installed everything as usual: SDK, NDK, Eclipse IDE, JDK, etc.

On Eclipse it works fine, and the SDK is visible on:

```
Window > Preferences > Android > SDK Location: /home/user/android-sdks
```

I have also established the path to be able to run command on prompt terminal. To be absolutely sure that it would be set to work, I did it on following files ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc, as follows:

```
# Android Path
export ANDROID_SDK="/home/user/android-sdks"
export ANDROID_NDK="/opt/android/android-ndk-r7"
export PATH="$PATH:ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

Then, I reboot and run on terminal:

```
$ android
bash: android: command not found...
```

But if I go in the folder

```
/home/user/android-sdks/tools/
```

and try on terminal:

```
./android
```

Then android runs.

I tried many times, many ways, and nothing. What it is missing to get android properly set-up on my path, so I could run commands directly on terminal?

All suggestions and comments are highly appreciated and welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
ANDROID_SDK="/home/user/android-sdks"
ANDROID_NDK="/opt/android/android-ndk-r7"
PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_SDK/tools:$ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools:$ANDROID_NDK"
```

You've missed the `$` before the first use of `ANDROID_SDK` variable.